# Publish a post on Facebook using Open Graph, is it necessary send the Review Submission to Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm able to post a message on Facebook through my iOS app using my account of developer, but if I try to post by other devices using other accounts it doesn't work.

I receive an error:

> (com.facebook.sdk error 2).

My app is **not** in development mode. So I would know if I have to create an Open Graph Action or object and submit to Facebook the item for approval.

Because I've seen that under "Status & Review" there is the item "Submit Items for Approval".

Answer (score 0):

Yes you get that right. You have to Submit the Actions for Approval else nobody but the developers/testers can see the stories(even if the app is live).

They generally takes 3-4 working days for them to review. Explain each and every step carefully till the story is published to make sure that it'll not get rejected and you have to do the submissions again.

Comment: ok, so I have to create only an Action or also a story and an object? I've only to post a message and a photo. Actually I use     me/feed so my question is : if I create a new action I have to replace it with me/nameoftheaction ?

Comment: What kind of action are you using? default one or you have created one yourself?

Comment: Now I'm using the "feed" action to post a message

Comment: "feed" is not an action! Action is like: `I "ate" banana` `I ran "30 miles"` `I listened a "song"`. That's what open graph is for! I think you're quite confused with OG. Let me know what action are you using

Comment: My custom action is "suggest" a place like a restaurant, a bar, a shop because it is an app to save your favorite places.

Comment: mm. So add this action `suggest` and object `place`, and send it for the approval. That's it :)

Comment: You still stucked here?

Comment: but if I don't need to create an action and an object and I want to use simply the graphpath 'me/feed' to publish, is not possible ?

Comment: Of course it is possible. But you only said in the question that you are using the Open Graph Stories?

Comment: @SahilMittal The question is if i want to publish post to me/feed only, do i need to submit to get approval of Open Graph? I've tried to publish post to me/feed but didn't work.